# How to edit default security of object class in active directory using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As per the [Active Directory Cookbook](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/active-directory-cookbook/0596004648/ch14s12.html),

> Each instantiated object in Active Directory has an associated
> structural class that defines a default security descriptor (
> defaultSecurityDescriptor attribute). When an object is created, the
> default security descriptor is applied to it. This, along with
> inheritable permissions from the parent container, determines how an
> object’s security descriptor is initially defined.

It is possible to edit this in the `Active Directory Schema` MMC Snap-In in the `Default Security` Tab in the class properties.

How can I edit this default ACL using powershell?

(Preferrably, I would like to use `Get-ACL`/`Set-ACL`, because I am familiar with it.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use Get-ACL/Set-ACL for this, however you can edit the `defaultSecurityDescriptor` attribute like this:

```
$adSchema = (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext
$computerObject = Get-ADObject -SearchBase $adSchema -Filter "Name -eq 'Computer'" -Properties defaultSecurityDescriptor
$computerDefaultSecurityDescriptor = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor -ArgumentList @($false, $false, $computerObject.defaultSecurityDescriptor)

# make modifications to $computerDefaultSecurityDescriptor.DiscretionaryACL
# e.g. 
# $computerDefaultSecurityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl | where SecurityIdentifier -eq "S-1-3-0" | % $computerDefaultSecurityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.RemoveAce($_)

$newSDDL = $computerDefaultSecurityDescriptor.GetSddlForm([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All);'
Set-ADObject $ComputerObject -replace @{defaultSecurityDescriptor = $newSDDL}
```